# Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized. what to do?

Tags: c#

When I try to use the method `GetCities()`, it says:

> Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

Can anyone please advise on what to do?

```
public class CitiesService
{
    public DataSet DS;
    public OleDbConnection myConnection;
    public OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
    public OleDbDataAdapter adapter2;

    public CitiesService()
    {   
    }

    public DataSet GetCities()
    {
        OleDbCommand myCmd = new OleDbCommand("SPtblCities", myConnection);
        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        OleDbDataAdapter Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        Adapter.SelectCommand = myCmd;
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            Adapter.Fill(dataSet, "tblCities");
            dataSet.Tables["tblCities"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]
            { 
                dataSet.Tables["tblCities"].Columns["CityID"]
            };
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        return dataSet;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to instantiate and open a Connection.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive: with a `DataAdapter` you don't need to open/close the connection manually. `Fill` does it implitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the connection was not initialized, it is `null`.

Replace

```
public OleDbConnection myConnection;
```

with

```
public OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
```

or in the method:

```
myConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
OleDbCommand myCmd = new OleDbCommand("SPtblCities", myConnection);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use this pattern and remember that some of these objects are disposable.

```
public class CitiesService
{
    public DataSet DS;
    public OleDbConnection myConnection;
    public OleDbDataAdapter adapter;
    public OleDbDataAdapter adapter2;

    public CitiesService()
    {

    }



    public DataSet GetCities()
    {
        using (DataSet dataSet = new DataSet()) 
        {
            using (OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
            {           
                myConnection.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand myCmd = myConnection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter Adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        Adapter.SelectCommand = myCmd;
                        try
                        {

                            Adapter.Fill(dataSet, "tblCities");
                            dataSet.Tables["tblCities"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dataSet.Tables["tblCities"].Columns["CityID"] };
                        }
                        catch (OleDbException ex)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }
                }
                myConnection.Close();
            }
            return dataSet;
        }
    }

}
```